# Django celery results does not store task results

Tags: python, django

The problem speaks for itself - django-celery-results does not store any task results.

I did everything as it was described in 'getting started' section in documentation, but still no results.

I'm using django 4.1.2 and django-celery-results 2.4.0

Here is related variables from settings.py:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.redis.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': 'redis://redis:6379',
    }
}
CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER", "redis://redis:6379")
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ.get("CELERY_BACKEND", "django-db")
CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = "django-cache"
CELERY_RESULT_EXTENDED = True
```

I also tried database cache - nothing changed. How can I get this to work?

**UPD:** I can create TaskResult and GroupResult objects manually with django admin panel or django shell, the problem is that they are not created automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to migrate first then you will able to store such information.Follow this link you will get your solution for sure:

https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html#django-celery-results-using-the-django-orm-cache-as-a-result-backend

Comment: Yes, i already ran it, but still no results.
I forgot to mention it - i can create task result objects with django admin panel

Comment: Yes, you can do it from admin panel too.

Comment: any updates? I'm also not able to display task results when using django-cache as results_backend

Comment: your configs should be like this,

BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = "Asia/Kolkata"
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERY_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 30 * 60
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'

in settings.py file